# OAuth Domain can't satisfy redirect_uri AND Proxy url

Tags: support, oauth2, authentication

Let's say I have an app called ExampleApp, with these details:

```
Client ID:     12345
Key:           ThisIsTheKey123()
OAuth Domain:  exampleapp.com

[√] Enable Client Side OAuth flow
[√] Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri
```

I'm using the JavaScript SDK 2.0 to authenticate the user. When this code runs:

```js
SE.authenticate({
    "success": function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    "error": function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    "scope": ["private_info"],
    "networkUsers": true
});
```

I get the error message

> `redirect_uri` is not under the registered domain for this application

Reading the URL bar tells me that the `redirect_uri` is

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?assisted=12345&protocol=https&proxy=https%3A%2F%2Fexampleapp.com%2Fblank&scope=private_info&state=5
```

So I set my OAuth Domain to `stackexchange.com` and tried again. I was able to authenticate, but then it ended up on this screen:

[(Click for a larger view)

[image: unexpected domain or proxy url]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slmNl.png)

> **error description:** unexpected domain or proxy url

The proxy URL is the `channelUrl` I had supplied in `SE.init`! I still don't get any of the console messages from the success and error handlers, which means it hasn't returned anything yet. There *is* an `access_token` and `expires` in the URL hash, so it did properly authenticate (any my user count went up by one), but I'm not getting anything back because of the error.

Now what? If my OAuth Domain is `stackexchange.com`, then my proxy is not recognized. If it is set to `exampleapp.com` where my proxy is recognized, then authentication can't start because the `redirect_uri` is not recognized. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to uncheck `Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri`. This will allow your app to redirect to `stackexchange.com` without requiring it in the OAuth Domain. Your OAuth domain is for your own domain, where your proxy/channel URL resides, in this case `exampleapp.com`.

Your details should look like this now:

```
Client ID:     12345
Key:           ThisIsTheKey123()
OAuth Domain:  exampleapp.com

[√] Enable Client Side OAuth flow
[ ] Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri
```